# How to limiting text length in richtextbox in silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox, silverlight-5.0

I am working on one silverlight application and i am having problem with setting text limit in richtextbox.

How can i solve my problem??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think richtextbox has a max length for the text. You will have to subscribe to the [OnTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.ontextinput%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event of the rich text box, and then manually check if the text limit has been reached. If the limit has been reached, then set the Handled property of the event args to true.